# Loss of vector line accuracy when exporting from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, accuracy

[image][image]

I'm new to QGIS and having a little trouble understanding why my vector lines in QGIS look sharp and accurate but when I export and then import into MapBox, the line accuracy is reduced.

Vector end points shift a little and don't meet correctly anymore. There seems to be some vector simplification happening during export?

I've tried multiple export formats and they all provide the same result. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you Screenshot an example of what is happening?

Comment: Also please provide the CRS you're exporting from/to, and the exact export settings.

Comment: Thanks... I've tried exporting as CRS, EPSG:3857 and 4326... in both GeoJSON and ShapeFile formats. Not sure which CRS MapBox accepts? But when I try exporting in 3857, I get errors from MapBox about unacceptable bounding values.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but have your tried re-importing the GeoJSON and the vector tiles into QGIS (need 3.14+ for vector tiles)? Would let you pinpoint where the loss of precision is happening. And what's your scale, i.e. how big is the loss of precision?

Comment: Thanks, I tried re-importing the exported GeoJSON file back in QGIS and there was no loss of precision. So I guess that tells me the loss is occurring during the import to MapBox.

Answer (score 5):

**First off:** *Mapbox GL* [accepts](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/geography/) `EPSG:4326 - WGS84` referenced coordinates only, and transforms to either `EPSG:3857 - Spherical (Web) Mercator` directly, or into *Vector Tile* space.

**Then:** *Mapbox GL* internally scales down precision to 6 decimal digits for the use in GeoJSON based sources (the [GeoJSON specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) continues to suggest to [reduce precision to 6 decimal places](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-11.2)), or for their *Vector Tiles*.

**And eventually:** *Vector Tile* geometries are usually generalized for different zoom level presentations, their vertices reduced and simplified, and coordinates rounded to *Vector Tile* space ordinates. Note that GeoJSON sources are also simplified and transformed (see their [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt) library) to *Vector Tile* space internally.

**It seems to be one needs to expect reduced precision, considering the operations performed on the source geometries.** This is the price for the overall performance gain needed to serve arbitrary large geo-datasets in real-time to a client WebGL renderer.

Comment: Thanks, you may be right and I'll have to accept the difference.

But it's interesting that I can display the exact same vector lines in MapBox, from the pre-loaded MapBox Streets v8, which look accurate and precise (see image above). Yet that same data when imported in to MapBox manually as a GeoJSON layer, there is a noticeable loss of precision.

Only reason I'm not using the data from the MapBox Streets v8, is the lack of control over zoom-levels from the OSM source.